# mkdir(): Permission problems

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, mkdir

Im getting denied running the following function (which is located in
/var/www/mysite/public_html/app/Controllers/Script.php)

```
$structure = '/var/www/mysite/public_html/app/Controllers/folder1/newfolder';


if (!mkdir($structure, 0755, true)) {

  die();

}
```

I dont want to give to the web server general root permissions and also I want to keep folder1 in 755.

What I did is to edit the sudoers file trying to give to apache root permisions just in that specific path, I added this line:

```
 www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:
 /var/www/mysite/public_html/app/Controllers/Script.php
```

However Im still getting the same error, what is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about php but must likely you is running them scripts with the wrong user

check who’s the owner of the dir.

```sh
$ ls -lash
```

change ownership.

```sh
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/dir
```

- chown changes owner
- ‘-R’ change the ownership of subdirs and files
- $USER current user